# MS Access VBA : Pushing form information to web

Tags: ms-access, web, vba

The issue I am having is connect my Save_Record (suppose to save and push info) & btnExit (saves & exits) to push the information inputted on the form to be pushed out to the web database. The only way it will push the information is if I exit out, come back in and make a small change then it will push it out.

How can I achieve this without doing this?

```js
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**
Private Sub btnCancel_Click()       '==**== undo changes
  On Error Resume Next
  RunCommand acCmdUndo
  Err = 0
End Sub


'-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**
Private Sub btnExit_Click()
  DoCmd.Close
End Sub



Private Sub cmdViewPDF_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_cmdViewPDF_Click

    Dim stDocName As String
    Dim stLinkCriteria As String

    stDocName = "frm_Images"
    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria
    
Exit_cmdViewPDF_Click:
Exit Sub

Err_cmdViewPDF_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_cmdViewPDF_Click

    

End Sub



'-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
 'DoCmd.Save

End Sub



Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
[DT_MOD] = Now()
[MstrWinUser] = Forms!frFilter!txtWinUser
End Sub



'-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**
Private Sub MOREoperInfo_Click()
Dim DocName As String
Dim LinkCriteria As String

    DoCmd.Save
    DocName = "frmsearch"
    DoCmd.OpenForm DocName, , , LinkCriteria

End Sub
'-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**
'Save record and close
Private Sub Save_Record_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Save_Record_Click
[DT_MOD] = Now()
[MstrWinUser] = Forms!frmFilter!txtWinUser



'MsgBox "Saving frm_View"
'Save the record
'If there was a record already in txt box, we will assume it has been created in web
If Trim(txtEOCIncident.Value & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then
    Me.txtEOCPushFlag = "0"
    RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    DoCmd.Save
Else
    'SET EOC PUSH FLAG
    Me.txtEOCPushFlag = "1"
    RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    DoCmd.Save
    
    'TRY TO UPDATE WEB DATA
    If (pushEOCData(Me.ID)) Then
        'CLEAR PUSH FLAG AND SET PUSHDATE
        Me.txtEOCPushFlag = "0"
        Me.txtEOCPushDate = Now()
        RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
        DoCmd.Save
    End If
End If

    
Exit_Save_Record_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Save_Record_Click:
MsgBox Error$
Resume Exit_Save_Record_Click
End Sub


'*** 08-20-13 New code. Creates PDF of the Report.


Private Sub btnSaveasPDF_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_btnSaveasPDF_Click
Dim db As Database, rs As Recordset
Dim vFN As String, vPATH As String, vFile As String
Dim blRet As Boolean
Dim stDocName As String
Dim strConstantName As String
    stDocName = "rpt_Out"
'added 2014-09-02, MAB
strConstantName = "REPORT_FOLDER"
vPATH = Trim(DLookup("[ConstantValue]", "dbo_Constants", "[ConstantName] = '" & [strConstantName] & "'"))

If Forms!frm_View![DIST] = "1" Or Forms!frm_View![DIST] = "2" Or Forms!frm_View![DIST] = "3" Or Forms!frm_View![DIST] = "4" Then
    vFN = Forms!frm_View![ID] & "_" & Forms!frm_View![Typeofreport] & "_" & Month(Now()) & "_" & Day(Now()) & "_" & Year(Now()) & "_" & Hour(Now()) & Minute(Now()) & ".pdf"
    'vPATH = "\\...\...\Reports\"
    vFile = vPATH & vFN
    
Else
    MsgBox "Please enter your number." & vbCrLf & "It must be a single digit.", vbOKOnly Or vbInformation, "*****"
End If

'write to IMAGES
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("IMAGES")
rs.AddNew
rs!SPL_FILENAME = vFN
rs!SPL_ID = [Forms]![frm_View]![ID]
rs!SPL_MOD_DT = Format$(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")
rs!SPL_DOC_TYP = Forms!frm_View![DOC_TYP]
rs!SPL_FILELOC = vFile
rs!SPL_ACTIVE = "-1"
rs.Update
rs.Close

DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt_OUT", acViewPreview
DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, stDocName, acFormatPDF, vFile
MsgBox "An image of this report has been saved.", vbOKOnly Or vbInformation, "*****"



Exit_btnSaveasPDF_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_btnSaveasPDF_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_btnSaveasPDF_Click
    
End Sub

********************PUSHEOCDATA*******************************************

'* iSpillID is the value of SPILL_ID from Spills table for the
'* the record you want to update
'*
'*******************************************************************************

Public Function pushEOCData(iSpillID As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim db As Database
    Dim sSql As String
    Dim strStoredProcSql As String
    Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim sEOCIncident As String
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim iEOCSpillID, iEOCMat1ID, iEOCMat2ID As Long
    Dim iReturn As Integer
    Dim dAmount1 As Double
    Dim dAmount2 As Double
    Dim sSpillResponse As String
    Dim sMaterialResponse As String
    Dim sEOCSpillID, sEOCMat1ID, sEOCMat2ID As String
    Dim iFoundAt As Long
    Dim iStart As Long
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim bReturn As Boolean
    
    
    Dim objSpillNode As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim objMaterialsNodes As IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim objMaterialNode As IXMLDOMNode
    pushEOCData = True
    
    initWEBEoc
    iEOCSpillID = -1
    iEOCMat1ID = -1
    iEOCMat2ID = -1
    
    'RETRIEVE INCIDENT NUMBER FROM DATABASE and associated data
    'from the database.  Note: this is a stored procedure
    
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")
    qdef.Connect = CurrentDb.TableDefs("usysWellHistory").Connect

    qdef.ReturnsRecords = True
    '
    ' This stored procedure is written to return a record set with
    ' fields named the same as in webeoc.
    '
    'strStoredProcSql = "EXEC RBDMS.SPILL_QUERY  @N_SPILLID=" & iSpillID
    strStoredProcSql = "{CALL RBDMS.SPILL_QUERY  (" & iSpillID & ")}"
    qdef.sql = strStoredProcSql
    
    Set rs = qdef.OpenRecordset
    'Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows
    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
        rs.MoveFirst 'Unnecessary in this case, but still a good habit
        sEOCIncident = rs!INCIDENTID_NUMBER
        If Len(sEOCIncident) < 1 Then
            pushEOCData = False
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        'Get the data from webeoc.
        'business rules say that we have to have data
        'in webeoc to continue
        iReturn = getSpillNode(sEOCIncident, objSpillNode)
        If iReturn < 1 Then
            'MsgBox "No WEBEoc data exists for EOC Incident: " & sEOCIncident
            pushEOCData = False
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        'grab the data id from the spill data, we will need this later to
        'update the materials
        sEOCSpillID = objSpillNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("dataid").Text
        iEOCSpillID = CLng(sEOCSpillID)
        If iEOCSpillID < 1 Then
            pushEOCData = False
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        bReturn = updateEOCSpillData(rs, objSpillNode)
        If bReturn = False Then
            pushEOCData = False
            Exit Function
        End If
            
        
        dAmount1 = rs!AMOUNT1
        dAmount2 = rs!AMOUNT2
        
        
        'Get the materials records from webeoc for this incident number.
        iResult = getMaterialNodes(sEOCSpillID, objMaterialsNodes)
        
        
        If dAmount1 > 0 Then
            'If webeoc has one or more materials records for the incident,
            'grab the first record and update it with dbase values
            If objMaterialsNodes.LENGTH > 0 Then
                Set objSpillNode = objMaterialsNodes.Item(0)
                'update materials
                updateEOCMaterialData rs, objSpillNode, 1
            Else
                'insert materials
                insertEOCMaterialData rs, 1, sEOCSpillID
            End If
        End If
        
        If dAmount2 > 0 Then
            'if webeoc has more than one materials record for the incident,
            'grab the second record and update it.
            
            If objMaterialsNodes.LENGTH > 1 Then
                Set objSpillNode = objMaterialsNodes.Item(1)
                'update materials
                updateEOCMaterialData rs, objSpillNode, 2
            Else
                'insert materials
                insertEOCMaterialData rs, 2, sEOCSpillID
            End If
        End If
        
    Else
        'MsgBox "No data needs to be pushed to webeoc for this spill."
        pushEOCData = True
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    rs.Close
    
    
End Function
```

Comment: I don't see anything here in regards to the web. Is this a Access application that is connected to office 365 or SharePoint?

Comment: Where is the code for 'pushEOCData'?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn sorry about that, I added to the bottom!

Comment: Well, the additional code you now show doesn't help much because it references at least three functions that are not shown in your post: getSpillNode, updateEOCSpillData, insertEOCMaterialData.  So, do you know if the issue is: (a) Record not added/updated to BACKEND DATABASE on click event; or (b) Record not displayed on your form? Since a close/reopen shows the data, I assume the issue is (b) - not refreshing.